# Dilemma about the identity of this plant: leopard lily? Silver squill?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers, ornamental-plant

I am searching for this plant.
[image]

Somebody said that it is leopard lily..others said it is silver squill.

Now when I google about "silver squill", [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledebouria_socialis) says:

> Ledebouria socialis, the silver squill, wood hyacinth, or leopard lily, is a geophytic species....

So, I guess, the other name of silver squill is leopard lily.

But, when I search for "silver squill flower",I get results like

[image]

[image]

which does not look like the first orange flower, the one I am searching for...nor the plant looks like the dotted leaves of squill either.

Please somebody help me out here. If I want to buy the plant producing flowers like picture 1, what plant should I search for at the nurseries ?

Comment: Normal problem with common names for plants. The same common name may refer to dozens of different plant species...

Comment: Going a step back on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopard_lily

Comment: There is absolutely nothing silver about the plant you posted, that should be your first clue that the ID is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poking around wikipedia for a few minutes, you appear to have *Iris domestica* as "what you want" under the common name leopard lily. So look for that (or, as commented and noted at wikipedia, *Belamcanda chinensis*) at a nursery.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_domestica

Comment: Spectra, as noted in the Wikipedia entry, this plant is also known by its old botanical name of Belamcanda chinensis. The horticulture trade changes names slowly, so you may have better luck finding it under the old name rather than as Iris domestica.

Comment: @Jurp the problem is, local nursery people here  in our place, the don't know or care about scientific/botanical names. They hear what other people say (which is a common name) and start selling them by those names. If I have to search the plant by its botanical name, then I will have to visit a Govt nursery/ horticulture centre which is faaaaar away from where I live.

Comment: Spectra - Guess I shouldn't be surprised that the nurseries use common names, although that must make selling "Pincushion Flowers" interesting (I know of five different pincushion flowers in the trade). If you can't find it under its Iris or leopard lily names, then I recommend that you look for it under Blackberry Lily (so-called because of its seeds); I know that in the US you can buy it online under that name.